# Div getting hidden on page reload/refresh

Tags: html, css

I have a live website that runs smoothly first load. However sometimes when you refresh the page my `.bx-wrapper` becomes hidden behind my background video `.landing_wrap`.

Its only happens on page refresh, and seems that it is still there, just not displaying like it should.

Live site: http://www.factormedia.co.za/

HTML:

```
<!--===================================================Landing_page===================================================!-->
<div class="landing_wrap">
    <div class="quote">
        <p>Don't beg for things, do it yourself or else you won't get anything.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="landing">
        <video id="landingbg" autobuffer width="100%" height="100%" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay"  loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
            <source src="videos/vid1_bg.m4v" poster="../images/Comp%201_00044.png"/>
        </video>
        <div class="main_logo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--===================================================Fader===================================================!-->
<div class="faderwrap">
        <div class="faderz">
                <img src="images/fader2.png" />
                <img src="images/fader1.png" />
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.landing_wrap{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    padding: 0;
    top:-20px;
    *zoom: 1;
    z-index:4002;
    width:100%;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
/** THEME
===================================*/
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {  
    left: 0px;
    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't, at least here

Comment: strange. U tried multiple refreshes?

Comment: Might be ad blocking extension.

Comment: It could be my adBlock. Maybe the plugin has similar traits to what an advert may have and its taking that as one